# Unable to access my published web page from other computers

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-7, publish

I have published ASP.NET web site, using IIS7 on Win7. I can access this web site on my localhost, but it is inaccessable from other computers via internet. I have tried to disable firewall and anti-virus program, but with no success.

Does anyone know what may be causing this problem?

It works fine if I publish it on winXP.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out your router settings for port 80 forwarding;
Check out information about your internet provider as well;
There are providers that block port 80 outgoing traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to see if the website is actually bound to 127.0.0.1. If it is, it would work for you but no one else.

Comment: It is not bound for 127.0.0.1

Comment: Are you using DNS aliasing or IPs to access it? If you're using DNS, are you able to ping/tracert the IP?

Answer (score 0):

Try to hit the website from a different computer on the internal network.  If you can't hit it internally, then it is an issue with the local configuration on the webserver.  If you can hit it internally, but can't hit it externally, then there is some kind of routing issue from the outside.

Its likely a routing issue from the outside, so think about these steps:

1. External DNS
2. Proper NAT/Firewall settings
3. Try using telnet to connect to the website and see if you get a response
4. Use tracert from the outside to see where the traffic is failing (if its failing)

Answer (score 0):

Check the security settings on the deployed folder and check "Everyone" has read access. If you've not deployed under wwwroot they may not